# Button 2 should start all the things in from button 1, but how?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, button

I To my knowledge, I am a complete beginner. what I know, I have taught myself.
I have the following problem.

I have a function that is executed by click. in this function are many other actions that are then executed. now I want a second button that does the same thing again first. but do not want to have to write all the actions again in the function.

surely there is a way that when i press the second button everything that is in button one is executed?

this is my code for button 1:

```
const navSextro = document.getElementById("navSextro")
navSextro.addEventListener("click", (ASC) => {

    for (let navbarBottomLogo of navbarBottomLogos) {
        navbarBottomLogo.style.display = "none"
    }

    for (let contactAdress of contactAdresses) {
        contactAdress.style.display ="none"
    }
    for (let btnleistung of btnleistungen) {
        btnleistung.style.display ="none"
    }
    bgStart.classList.remove("headSectionSextro")
    bgStart.classList.remove("headSectionMendel")
    bgStart.classList.remove("headSectionDaven")
    bgStart.classList.remove("headSectionMuenter")
    bgStart.classList.remove("headSectionWald")
    bgStart.classList.remove("headSectionRick")
    bgStart.classList.remove("headSectionIndustrie")

    bgStart.classList.add("headSectionSextro")

    for (let headTextStart of headTextStarts) {
        headTextStart.style.display = "none"
    }
    
    for (sextroBtnLeistung of sextroBtnLeistungen) {
        sextroBtnLeistung.style.display = "flex"
        sextroBtnLeistung.classList.remove("border-bottom-sextro", "border-bottom-mendel", "border-bottom-daven", "border-bottom-rick", "border-bottom-muenter", "border-bottom-wald", "border-bottom-industrie", )
        sextroBtnLeistung.classList.add("border-bottom-sextro")
    }

    let contactAdressSextro = document.getElementById("kontakt-adress-sextro")
    contactAdressSextro.style.display ="block"

    startSextro.style.display = "block"

    navstart.style.display = "flex"
    navlogo.style.display = "flex"

    sectionOne.style.display ="flex"
    sectionTwo.style.display ="flex"
    sectionThree.style.display ="flex"

    navSecBottom.style.display ="flex"

    mapText.style.display ="none"
    philosophie.style.display ="none"
    bewertungen.style.display ="none"

    const navbottom = document.getElementById("navBottom")
    navbottom.style.display ="none"

    const navAboutUs = document.getElementById("navaboutus")
    navAboutUs.style.display ="none"

    //SET BORDER-BOTTOM COLOR

    let borderSectionThree = document.getElementById("kontakt-adress-sextro")
    borderSectionThree.classList.remove("border-bottom-sextro", "border-bottom-mendel", "border-bottom-daven", "border-bottom-rick", "border-bottom-muenter", "border-bottom-wald", "border-bottom-industrie")
    borderSectionThree.classList.add("border-bottom-sextro")
    
    /*STICKY NAVBAR SEXTROSTRASSE*/
    window.onscroll = function() {stickyNavBarSextro()}
    const stickySextro = document.getElementById("navSecBottom").offsetTop

    function stickyNavBarSextro() {
        if(window.pageYOffset > stickySextro) {
            navSecBottom.classList.add("sticky")
        } else {
            navSecBottom.classList.remove("sticky")
        }
    }
    
})
```

And now i need a the code for the second button to activate all from button 1. But how?

Comment: Create a function, move your code from button 1 and call the new function every where you need.

Comment: hi @skowng you can extract all what happens in button 1 event listener into an external function so that when you add a click event listener on button 2, you just call the same function.

Answer (score 0):

You could make this into a named function and call that when the button is pressed.
Also you could try splitting everything up into smaller functions, so they do less things.
A function should only do a single thing.